# Is it possible to round excel entry in X cell to multiple of Y cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I think I'm going to be told that this is only possible with vba, which I am not familiar with, but here goes...

I have a spreadsheet where sales volumes are forecast in cell V5.  There is also a cell with pallet qty, H5.  What I would like is to enter a forecast figure into V5, and for that same cell to be auto-rounded to the nearest multiple of the H5 cell.  This applies to each row below row 5 as well.

Am I right in thinking this can't be done in excel alone?  If I need to include vba code, I'm not really sure what I am doing.  I have tried using code found from various searches but to no avail.

Is anybody able to help?

If I need to go RTFM just let me know =)

Many thanks in advance.

Luke =)

Comment: So you manually enter a value in V5 and you want it to change to the number of pallets needed based on H5?  Or is V5 a formula that calculates the forecast off other factors?

Comment: A formula will just be lost when you type in the forecast so VBA is probably the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks Stephen =)

Scott, just to confirm, I want to enter a value in V5 and for the value in V5 to be rounded to a multiple of the pallet qty (H5).  So if I entered 135000 and the pallet qty is 13200, it will round the figure I type into V5 to 132000 once I tab out of the cell.

Comment: Then it will require vba in a Worksheet_Change event.  SuperUser is not a code for me site.  Try it on your own and when you get stuck post your code attempts and the exact problem that you are trying to overcome specific to the code you posted on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: No worries, I thought that might be the case, will persevere and see if I can make any progress, thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is a spreadsheet, not a programming language. What you are asking for is that a single cell contains the typed-in value *plus* a formula that modifies it right away; that is not possible.
Each cell can only contain one of the two.

A simple solution would be to type the number in one cell, and have another cell - next to it - show the rounded value.
A more complex solution is to write VB code that acts on typing a value, and replaces it with a rounded value.

Comment: Hi Aganju.
Due to the nature of the spreadsheet, and it being quite wide already, it would be preferable to not add further columns for usability reasons.  I and other users will likely be using on small laptops so keeping it both compact and simple for the other users would be good.

I've tried to use vb options that I have found online but they don't seem to work, and I'm not familiar with vb in order to troubleshoot what may be wrong.

Comment: Ok, looks like you'll need VB. The code should be rather simple, but I am not able to write it. Maybe you are lucky and someone writes it an answer.

Comment: @Doom, just a suggestion: What you're describing is generally bad practice.  If the need relates just to the sheet dimensions, insert the extra column and then hide that column.  That will give you a simple, clean solution without changing the sheet size.

Comment: Hi Fixer, I don't think that would work, as the separate columns would both need to be visible; one for forecast entry, and the other for the corrected entry which would need to be checked =)  It's down to a combination of dimensions and ease for users; it would be fiddly for them to try and work their forecast to the nearest pallet quantity manually, and having the 2 columns there several times for the several months forecast on the sheet makes it quite large.

Comment: @Doom, use a smaller font so more fits.  :-)